# javax.websocket.Session - which map implementation is getUserProperties() returning?

Tags: java, session, websocket

I am currently deploying on jetty, but I guess every implementation is following one and the same concept. So is it returning a HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap or whatever. I tried to check the implementation sources for WebsocketSession for Jetty, but inside I did not find the place where the user properties are initialized with the map. Well for jetty I could use the debugger to check what instance of the user properties is assigned to the sessions, but this is not answering the question, whether other application servers will do the same.

Does anyone know the answer? SearchWebSites are mostly returning tutorials on websockets and cannot get an answer to this specific question

Comment: Why you wan't to rely on the implementation? The cause of hiding the implementation behind the interface is to prevent dealing with the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tyrus implementation

As for Tyrus, I had a look at the [`TyrusSession.java`](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/TyrusSession.java) implementation. The extract which interests you is (numbers refer to row):

```
87   public class TyrusSession implements Session, DistributedSession {

104      private final Map<String, Object> userProperties;

127      TyrusSession(...) {
191          userProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
192      }

... }
```

So it's a basic HashMap. However, you should **NOT** rely on the implementation. Here is why the signature is defined by a `Map<String, Object>` and not a `ConcurrentHashMap` or any sophisticated stuff:

### User properties:

As defined in Section 2.1.2 of [**JSR 359**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=359):

> Developers may use the user property map accessible through the **getUserProperties()** call on the **Session** object to associate application specific information with a particular session. The websocket implementation must preserve this session data for later access until the completion of the **onClose()** method on the endpoint instance. [WSC 2.1.2-2]. After that time, the websocket implementation is permitted to discard the developer data.

<sub>emphasis from JSR</sub>

The user properties map is specific to a given websocket session only, so there is no point of having a concurrent access. You may have another object involving multiple sessions but that would a object on your own so you decide whatever you want to use.

### One session = One server endpoint instance

I'd like to add a note on the fact that your server endpoint is not a singleton: It is expected to have one instance of your endpoint per peer (session). From *section 5.1* of **JSR 359**:

> Unless backed by a Java EE component with a different lifecycle (See Chapter 7), the container must use a unique instance of the endpoint per peer. [WSC-5.1-1] In all cases, the implementation must not invoke an endpoint instance with more than one thread per peer at a time. [WSC-5.1-2] The implementation may not invoke the close method on an endpoint until after the open method has completed. [WSC-5.1-3]
>
> This guarantees that a websocket endpoint instance is never called by more than one container thread at a time per peer. [WSC-5.1-4]

In a nutshell, during websocket designing, when dealing with user properties and more globally when dealing with collections:

1. One session has its own instance or your `@ServerEndPoint`
2. Do **NOT** assume that websocket are thread-safe
3. Only rely on the specification, do not rely on implementation

---

<sub>**Side node regarding user properties in `javax.websocket.session`:**</sub>

<sub>Please note that `userProperties` is merely instantiated and not populated from any other map. I highlight this point in case you're using a [custom *Configurator*](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/websocket010.html) by extending [`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html): If you put some data in the `ServerEndpointConfig.getUserProperties()`, they will not be automatically copied in the `Session.getUserProperties()`.</sub>